# Adding or subtracting values based on a vector of check boxes in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas, sumifs

I hope you can help me with this:

I'm trying to create a savings-control sheet where I list my monthly payment and I'm trying to use the SUMIF formula to subtract my expenses by selecting what I have currently payed but I don't know if this may work with a vector of check boxes [Sheets sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP1Vh.png)

the current formula as you can see in the image works fine but only for column D however if I check the rest of the boxes nothing is subtracted

This is how the formula looks like now: =A31+A32-SUMIF(D3:J14,TRUE,C3:C14) however only works from D3 to D14 and I need it to work from D3 to J14

Any help will be highly appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is:

```
=A31+A32-SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(N(D3:J14)*C3:C14))
```

### Formula rundown

This formula is based on the function `N` that converts a boolean to an integer (1 for true, 0 for false). We can then multiply by the expense value. Here an example:

```
=N(D3)*C3
```

This will equal `C3` iff `D3` is checked.

Having that we can make the entire table with `ARRAYFORMULA`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(N(D3:J14)*C3:C14)
```

Now we can sum all the values to have the total expenses:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(N(D3:J14)*C3:C14))
```

Add the other cells and you get your result.

### References

- [N (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093357?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [SUM (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks bro...that worked!!! I'm not so familiar with ARRAYFORMULA nor the N function so thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=A31+A32-sumproduct((countif(if(D3:J14, row(D3:D14)), row(D3:D14))>0),C3:C14)
```

and see if that helps?